# Ubuntu Won't Open From Chrome

Tags: server, chromebook

I am currently using `Ubuntu 14.04` on an acer chromebook. I was using Ubuntu and running PlayonLinux with something uninstalling. I went to go back to Chrome OS to check if I was connected to the internet or not, but then when I went to go back into Ubuntu from Chrome, it wouldn't let me. So I tryed to get in through the crosh terminal and all that came up was:

```
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Not unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise as another instance is using it.
```

Could someone please help me get it back?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Crosh in Chrome. Type `shell` then after you can see the green Chronoslocal thing, then you type this in:

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -n precise -u
```